# Element must cover whole page except 20px margin

Tags: css

I need create element, that cover whole page except 20px margin on all sides. I try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/PiranhaGreg/mZw5K/) and it works in webkit browsers and Firefox, but Internet Explorer (10) and Opera have problem with this :-( . Any idea how to solve this?

**HTML**

```
<div id="first">
    <div id="second">
        Hello world!
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
head, body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body
{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    display: table;
}

#first
{
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}

#second
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: display:table property is not properly supported by IE and it is discouraged to use. Note: The values "inline-table", "table", "table-caption", "table-cell", "table-column", "table-column-group", "table-row", "table-row-group", and "inherit" are not supported in IE7 and earlier. IE8 requires a !DOCTYPE. IE9 supports the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a solution like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/cyHmD/

**Never** use `position:absolute` and `display:table` on body - leave those properties as they are since body is your base from where you build the rest of the site - at most use position:relative on body tag. `box-sizing` changes how the browser box model is calculated - for example instead of calculating `100% width + 20% padding + 20% border = 140%` it calculates as `100% width + 20% padding + 20% border = 100%`.

This solution will work from IE7 on including IE7.

```
head, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body {
    background-color: blue;
}

#first
{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:20px;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

#second
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: A little bit buggy in Opera, but probably best solution if I shouldn't use `display:table`. Thanks ;-) !

Comment: @Matěj Pokorný  What is the bug in opera? We can solve that too. Altough I wouldn't bother much about opera - usage is damn low and they are abbandoning their Presto engine anyway soon to switch on webkit.

Comment: Opera responds only on horizontal resizing ([1](https://qr9fkg.blu.livefilestore.com/y2plH3y4yUyMA9qeiuileypltr3DyLVJBct22Xqk0gSLzSrxjL2eR0jinJBi54_Ph2Wk8YvbFjmjl2hsULobloDmruvvKR2y-31RDzli00LRGK3GAj-CM5MOV9VKhpFzO0f/opera1.jpg), [2](https://qr9fkg.blu.livefilestore.com/y2pbepS43yjk7nJh58lY9Iu9wVAHRakmYicn0fSWvlYX2FjbPwHmskNy6YTBEtZhR-bOap7yoh4fweut56oLmlUIitJIkmmk0fYN_BI7O0AEyGwMQwN7bu0fKf6BhxkcPVI/opera2.jpg)). But never mind ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest:

```
#first {
    display: table-cell;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}
```

Which will position the element `20px` away from each of the sides. However I'd suggest *not* using `display: table-cell;` since that requires a parent element to have `display: table-row` which itself then requires a parent element with `display: table`.

Also, it looks like you're trying to emulate table-based layouts, if you could list the overall problem you're trying to solve you may get better/more useful answers.

Comment: This will be buggy in IE8 and IE7 since they have problems rendering this technique without specifying width. Also IE7 does not support `table-cell`.

Answer (score 1):

How about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mZw5K/2/)? Simply replace required margin with border:

```
#first
{
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 20px solid blue;
    background-color: white;
}
```